# How can i get data from a dataset into a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a newbie in Web Developing. I am using C# in ASP.net

I created a Dataset that includes TableAdapters.

I.e. for my Table Product_family i created the ProductFamilyTableAdapter that includes the following columns prfm_description1, prfm_description2, prfm_description3, etc...

I have a method GetAllProductFamilies.

After that i created a Business Logic Layer class ProductFamiliesBLL.cs which includes the same functions.

In the Page_Load event of my master page i create

```
ProductFamiliesBLL prfLogic = new ProductFamiliesBLL()
```

and i can bind to a Datagrid

```
datagrid1.Datasource = prfLogic.GetAllProductFamilies();
datagrid1.Databind();
```

My question is if I can add this data into an array or a List and how?
How can i read one by one the retrieved rows and get data from first, second,..., n row from a specific column.

Comment: which version of framework you are using?

Comment: visual web developer 2010 express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As below you can loop through each row and each column of the row tha....and your code will be likw this...

```
foreach (DataRow dr in prfLogic.GetAllProductFamilies())
{
   foreach(DataColumn dataColumn in myDataTable.Columns)
    {
        string fieldValue = dr[dataColumn].ToString();   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, i will check during the day your answer.

Comment: @KostasL - welcom..just dont forget to mark it as accepted if its match with your requirement

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this. Try this code.

```
List<DataRow> list = new List<DataRow>(ds.tables(0).select());
```

Dont to forget to mark as answer if this helps yu.

Comment: i did it? sorry my mistake. I did not check yet.

Comment: Downvote from me. It can't possibly compile, casing is wrong, on top of that parens are used for the indexer on the Tables-property. My guess is that you - if you tested this - wrote the code in VB and then converted to C# (or at least tried to convert it). Even though VB is not case sensitive it's certainly sloppy code and I would probably down vote it even if it actually was VB. Beyond that it doesn't really answer the question, the question was how to get the value from a specific column.